# Cross-checking a list of users with users on a db - bad idea?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

Lets say. If i have 1,000,000 users registered on my system and I have a list of 500 names.

I would like to crosscheck these names against the number of users on my system to see which names / users are already registered on the db.

Will such a process slow down the app significantly? Or does this sort of thing happen all the time?

Perhaps I can cache the results every 30 mins so I don't have to call it every time.

**EDIT >> A bit of clarification:**

I forgot to mention that I am trying to udate the list of 500 names. So if 'foobar' and 'joe' is on this list and is also registered in the db, then all I want to do is remove 'foobar' and 'joe' from the list, giving me 498 names.

I don't think it would be suitable to do something like:

```
User.where('name in (?)', Array('foobar', 'joe'))
```

I would have do something like:

```
User.each do |registered_user|
  index = list.index(list.find{ |user| user.screen_name.downcase == registered_user.screen_name.downcase })
  list.delete_at(index) if index
end

filtered_list = list
```

Is above code, overkill?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do it cleverly, it can be very fast.  Let the database do the work.

```
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE Name IN ( <generated list of your 500 user name candidates>)
```

The returned list will be the ones of the 500 which already exist in the database.  Such as call will be fast, at most a few seconds on a slow database.

Cheers,
Daniel

Comment: Also make sure the name is indexed.

Comment: Is it better to do the crosschecking on the db level or on the app level?

Comment: It is best to make as few queries to the database as possible, as the roundtrip to the database is orders of magnitude slower than running in-memory code.  The database should be able to  perform this query very quickly, especially if you index the name column.  So let the DB do the work.  It's a simple query and little can go wrong.

Comment: be careful of the following if you are generating the list in code (as opposed to a subquery) - 1) sql injection attacks 2) some DBs have a limit on the size of the 'IN' clause, so I think that 500 entries may be a bit dicey depending on the size of the data.

Comment: Oracle has a limit of 1000 elements in the list.  So when using Oracle I break my clauses into sets of 998 or so.

Answer (score 1):

Any modern relational DB worth it's salt should easily be able to process 500 checks against the DB without affecting other queries, **provided** that your tables are structured properly (unique keys, indexes on frequently searched fields, etc)